# What benefits are there to getting Stack Overflow reputation over 10k?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, badges, privileges

I read many articles related to Stack Overflow reputation, such as the following: http://robertgreiner.com/2010/10/10000-stackoverflow-rep/

It states:

> "The final milestone in this reputation scheme is at 10,000 reputation. At this level, you gain the highest level of privilege possible without being elected a community moderator."

Apart from that my knowledge will increase, I have some questions in mind.

- What will happen if someone is elected as a community moderator?
- Can the reputation help programmers clear a job interview?

Or

- Can I sell my reputation for money?

What additional benefits can I get from reputation above 10k?

Comment: You're so far away from 10.000 that you shouldn't even think about it. First and foremost you have to prove that you're competent enough by giving useful answers and also patient enough to help others!

Comment: @user143091 i know how can i increase my reputation,,, read my question again !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What will happen if someone is elected as a community moderator?

They will become janitors of the site, [more or less](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166623/what-is-a-day-in-the-life-of-a-stack-overflow-moderator-like). They get to do all the dirty work that the community can't do. It's certainly a privilege, but I don't always envy them.

> Can the reputation help programmers clear a job interview?

[Stack Overflow reputation getting you a job is unlikely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30578/is-stack-overflow-reputation-marketable). They are fake points on the intarwebz. It might help you get an interview however. I have heard of several cases where high-rep users were contacted because their excellent contributions (and associated rep) made them interesting enough to at least interview.

> Can I sell my reputation for money?

No you can't. If you would try by transferring large amounts of reputation, you would get found out pretty quickly. And it's more than likely that it would end up being a problem for all parties involved. So you could just sell the whole account, right? Nope, [the TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) explicitly states that the agreement applies to you only and is not transferable without explicit permission. And you would be pretty unlikely to get that permission.

> What additional benefits can I get from reputation above 10k?

Knowledge, most of all. The more you participate and the more you answer or ask, the more you'll learn. And you will have made the internet that much better. So knowledge and a good feeling.

Comment: +1 - *knowledge and a good feeling*

Comment: also, very important: confidence

Answer (score 1):

- Community moderators perform some safekeeping and cleaning on the website and overall attempt to improve its quality. A moderator has access to more website features and can delete low quality posts way more easily.
- Reputation can not help you directly to pass many interviews I believe, but reputation is also related to your skills in both programming and communication. If your reputation is higher you will probably have better changes on interviews because you learned some skills that are essential to perform well on an interview.
- Reputation is a direct function on how much community trusts and respects you. You can see a full list of the privleges [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). You will also note that the highest cap is in fact 20K  not 10K of reputation.

  With the increase of reputation you will get access to more site privileges(and sometimes less annoying adds :) ). You can not sell your reputation as we don't care about money. We will not respect someone because he paid you, we will respect him for his own accomplishments.

Also from my experience I know that while getting to 10k reputation you will learn **a lot**(even in areas where you consider yourself an expert) and learning new things is always good for you.

Answer (score 0):

- when you are elected as a community moderator, you become a community moderator.
- this reputation will help in interviews if the interviewer accepts stackoverflow as a reference. try the careers 2.0 if you are looking for companies that value stackoverflow reputation
- you can not sell reputation. you can pass on your account to someone else or award bounties on questions.
- there are no benefits in terms of money.

maybe collect some reputation and learn how the system works before wondering how you can market it. read the link you posted more thoroughly. seems like you focused mainly on the 10.000 rep.

Comment: *"you can pass on your account to someone else"* ... well no, you can't. Technically perhaps, but legally not.